# 1 + ε approximation for non linear program

Tags: algorithms, optimization, approximation

Let us assume that we have the following (non linear) program :

R = min { ( (c1^T)*x + d1 ) / ( (c2^T)x + d2 ) : Ax<=b , (c2^T)*x+d2>0}

We also assume that the feasible solution area is bounded and that the objective value of the optimal solution belongs to [L,U].

We assume that we know a δ >0 , so that for every feasible solution x , ( c2^T)*x >= δ .

How can I prove that for every ε > 0 there is an ( 1 + ε) approximation of the solution of R? ( We can use a linear programming algorithm as subroutine). In addition , which is the time complexity of that algorithm?

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just hand you the solution; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/1284/98) for tips on asking questions about exercise problems. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]?

Comment: Welcome to [cs.SE]! Note that you can use LaTeX here to typeset mathematics in a more readable way. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands) for a short introduction.